# Change time zone in sms

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sms, timezone

I need to change the timezone to remove 6 hours compare to what SFMC is displaying in my SMS through Journey Builder.

For example, in Salesforce Service Cloud, I have an appointment at 6:00 AM, and with the code below, I have an SMS that is displaying 12:00 PM.

```
%%[
SET @d=Format(SystemDateToLocalDate(FormatDate(AttributeValue('Event:StartDateTime'), "iso")), "dd/MM/yyyy à h:mm" , "date")=
]%%
RDV confirmé le %%=v(@d)=%% chez MM %%Event:Magasin__r:Name%%
```

Can you correct me the correct code to have the good hour displaying?

Comment: Removing 6 hours is easy enough, but want to check if you can just simplify it first. What happens when you use SET @d = FormatDate(SystemDateToLocalDate("Event:StartDateTime"), "DD/MM/YYYY", "à hh:mm", "fr-FR")? And do you potentially need daylight savings applied at any time of year?

Comment: ok, i tried to simplify but I received the message with the code displaying. This is the full code I tried. 
SET @d = FormatDate(SystemDateToLocalDate("Event:StartDateTime"), "DD/MM/YYYY", "à hh:mm", "fr-FR")
RDV confirmé le %%=v(@d)=%% chez MM %%Event:Magasin__r:Name%%.

Comment: You still need the AMPScript block code in there eg %%[ SET @d = FormatDate(SystemDateToLocalDate("Event:StartDateTime"), "DD/MM/YYYY", "à hh:mm", "fr-FR") ]%%
RDV confirmé le %%=v(@d)=%% chez MM %%Event:Magasin__r:Name%%

Comment: And yes I will need a daylight savings applied at any time of year :)

Comment: This code is working but I just need to add 6 hours in the hour displayed. Can you help me ? %%[ SET @d=Format(SystemDateToLocalDate(FormatDate(AttributeValue('Event:StartDateTime'), "iso")), "dd/MM/yyyy à h:mm" , "date")=]%%
RDV confirmé le %%=v(@d)=%% chez MM %%Event:Magasin__r:Name%%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you want is:

```
%%[ SET @d = FormatDate(DateAdd(SystemDateToLocalDate("Event:StartDateTime"), 6, "H"), "DD/MM/YYYY", "à hh:mm", "fr-FR") ]%%
RDV confirmé le %%=v(@d)=%% chez MM %%Event:Magasin__r:Name%%
```

That will add on 6 hours. If you want to subtract 6 hours change the 6 to -6.

Comment: It is working, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to deduct 6 hours, you can use the [DateAdd](https://ampscript.guide/dateadd/) AMPscript function and make your code look like that -

```
%%[
SET @d = Format(SystemDateToLocalDate(FormatDate(DateAdd(AttributeValue('Event:StartDateTime'), -6, "H"), "iso")), "dd/MM/yyyy à h:mm" , "date")
]%%
RDV confirmé le %%=v(@d)=%% chez MM %%Event:Magasin__r:Name%%
```

This however will not consider Daylight Saving Time and there are pretty much 2 options:

- Remember to take into account when needed and update the code/dates manually.
- Try to tweak the dates via SQL in advance with the `AT TIME ZONE` function. Check out this [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/its-timezone-finally-real-convert-function-salesforce-jack-hobbs/) to understand how it works, yet the result is not guaranteed.